# $('.class').click() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a jQuery function which execute when a button which contains the class `button-trash` is clicked. The problem is that there is no reaction when I click on the button but the `alert` in the `$(document).ready(function()` works.

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_flotte">
<div class="div_avion" style="display:none;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="input-group" style="width:200px">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">F-BEN</span>
              <input type="text" name="avions[][immat]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : 49" >
          </div>
          <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
              <button class="btn btn-danger button-trash" type="button" name="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Marque</span>
              <input type="text" name="avions[][marque]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : Airbus" >
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Modèle</span>
             <input type="text" name="avions[][modele]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : 737" >
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">IATA</span>
              <input type="text" name="avions[][iata]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : 738" >
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Type de vol</span>
              <select name="avions[][type]" class="form-control-inline">
                <?php
                  foreach ($types_vol_avion as $cle => $value) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$cle.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                  ?>
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Transport</span>
              <select name="avions[][activite]" class="form-control-inline">
                <?php
                  foreach ($Activite_avion as $cle => $value) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$cle.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                  ?>
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button-trash').click(function(){
            alert("test");
        });
        alert("test");
});
```

**EDIT :**
The div `.div_avion`is created dynamicly by this function :

```
function AddAvion()
{
$( ".div_avion" ).eq(0).clone().attr({id:'div_avion'+($(".div_avion").length+1), style:'display:visible;'}).css('display', 'visible').appendTo( "#div_flotte" );
}
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to simulate your problem please?

Comment: you have a `display: none;` set to the `.div_avion` element. could that be the cause, I am not sure.

Comment: Hm... is your button dynamically created, by jquery? http://jsfiddle.net/d6sefghr/ Your code works fine, btw...

Comment: Your code seems to be right. it might be a html/css problem? does any other element cover up your button-trash buttons?

Comment: @Tahir Ahmed No because the div is cloned and the dispay property is set to visible before clicking on the trash button

Comment: @nevermind Yes my button is created dynamically by the following function : `$( ".div_avion" ).eq(0).clone().attr({id:'div_avion'+($(".div_avion").length+1), style:'display:visible;'}).css('display', 'visible').appendTo( "#div_flotte" );`

Comment: use on event to do that `$(".button-trash").on("click", function(){
});`

Comment: I suppose in that case, you ought to do `$(document).on('click', '.button-trash', function() { ... });`.

Comment: Execute the click listener code after the code that creates the button dynamicly and pushes it into the DOM. For example after the append() function. Attaching the button click event to an element that is not in the DOM yet, will not work.

Comment: @TahirAhmed That works ! You can put your comment as an answer. thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All right. Since you are creating a dynamic element, you can add your event like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-trash', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I never realised you had to use the on method when the html was dynamically created? I use the .click function even when it's dynamically created, it still works.

Comment: Hmm. Based on my experience, I do have to use `.on()` for dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 1):

If Dynamically produced button, then you should use the on() method

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.input-group').on('click','.button-trash', function(){
                    alert ('it is working');
                    alert("test");
                });
                alert("test");
        });    

    </script>
```